# How to give longitude and latitude value to google map script from a php variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps

I have a google map script like this which is the standard google map script provided in JQuery forum some where

```
<script type="text/javascript">          
/*
 * Google Maps documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html
 * Geolocation documentation: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html
*/
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#map-page", function() {
    <?php $coordenadas=explode(',',$fila['Googlemap']);?>
    var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>,<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?> ); 
    drawMap(defaultLatLng); // Default to Hollywood, CA when no geolocation support

    function drawMap(latlng) {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
        // Add an overlay to the map of current lat/lng
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Greetings!"
        });
    }
}); 
</script>
```

If you see in the code I am trying to pass longitude and latitude values extracted from a php variable to the function `draw_map();` . But I am not able to do that. Can someone please help me with this ?

**Edit-1**

Now the map is working with the solution provided by @sukhwinder but another problem is that the map is not centered to the screen . When I open in the mobile browser the marking is shown in the top left corner and the map is not visible totally .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your values are not enclosed with single quotes.

Corrected code:

```
var defaultLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng('<?php echo $coordenadas[0];?>','<?php echo $coordenadas[1];?>');
```

Comment: Thanks its working but I am facing a problem here that is when I use the default longitude /latitude which is LA (hollywood). In the mobile browser the map is centered properly . But When I give my own longitude /latitude and I open in the mobile browser it shows only top left corner of mobile do you know the reason ??

Comment: var latLng = marker.getPosition(); // returns LatLng object
map.setCenter(latLng); // setCenter takes a LatLng object

Comment: Can you explain more please I could not get it . Sorry I am new to all this

Comment: Its simple please go for google Maps APi, you are centering the map. Get exact location of the marker in the first line using marker.getPosition() and then set center using setCenter()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you exactly want to do but if you want to pass lat/
long values to a PHP page,

```
  var center = map.getCenter();
  var centerLat = center.lat();
  var centerLong = center.lng();
```

Then, as jon mentioned before, you can set the values to hidden
fields.
Or you can simply add the values to a query string.
e.g. http://foo.com/your_code.php?centerLat=...&centerLong=...

When the user submits the form, your PHP codes get the lat/long values
like

```
<?php
  $centerLat = $_REQUEST['centerLat'];
  $centerLong = $_REQUEST['centerLong'];

  // Store the values in your database.
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I already have a field in database with longitude/latitude values which I am extracting along with other details of the page and using it to display. In short its a house rental/selling page where I am showing the location of the add